# What type of relationship to add to these data models?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, entity, relationship

I'm having trouble with the last bit of my data model as I have no idea what type of relationship to add to these specific entities. I can't progress to the last part of the assignment which I can do easily if I don't pass this.

The case studies says,
"An employee works for a department at a particular branch. A branch will have multiple employees in different departments."

and

"A manager, who is an employee manages a department at a particular branch. Each department in every branch has one manager only. Also, start date and end date is stored for every manager's work employment history"

This is my current data model in the link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyumi.png

Any help or pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since `Departments` must have exactly one `manager` only, then you can add a field to `Departments` that will hold the `Employee.EmployeeID` of the manager. It appears that you have already done this part.

That field should be a foreign key `1:1` relationship with the `Employee` table. You can then also add the fields `manager_start_date` and `manager_end_date` to the `Department` table to track the `manager`'s employment range.

Note that an employee's start and end dates may not necessarily be their managerial start and end dates. Presumably someone could have started in `March` and then become a manager in `July`.

Ideally, the `PK` on `Department` would be `BranchID, Name`. Using `DepartmentID`is okay, but unnecessary with the requirements you've outlined in your question.

It is unclear to me from your snippet what exactly the relationship between `Department` and `Employee` currently is. There should be a `FK` reference to `Employee.employee_id` that would be made on `Department.manager_employee_id` and this would be a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Hello,
I think it's saying that each branch has many departments and each department has one manager.

Comment: Oh, it looks like you are correct. Let me take a second look and I'll edit my answer.